# Checking if API server is under maintenance

Tags: flask, server

I have a flask app with several API endpoints. I want to add a new endpoint that checks the server status and return a message (e.g. server is under maintenance or available).

My question is how do I know that the server is under maintenance and test this route on local?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any HTTP API responds with meaningful Status Codes and Status Messages. In particular:

> The ok read-only property of the Response interface contains a Boolean
> stating whether the response was successful (status in the range
> 200-299) or not.

```
if(response.ok){
  The API is alive!
}
```